# Why <p> and style display:block not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have trouble with HTML coding of my website. The problem is that tags

and element with `style="display:block"` are displayed in one line anyway. But each `block` must be in separate line. I use bootstrap 4.0.0 beta 2.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Here is real example https://codehint-web-ng.herokuapp.com/articles

Comment: put it inside a `div`

Comment: Try to add `width: 100%;` to `p`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `display: flex` defined the parent container (`.row`), that's why the block element are in the same line. The default behavior of the flex is to put all elements in the same line (`flex-direction:row`)

[image]

To fix this you may change the direction of flex to column by adding your own CSS or consider the builtin classes provided by bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#direction

[image]

Comment: This is native row class (I use Bootstrap 4 beta 2),  is it correct fix row? Maybe I can fix it locally?

Comment: @VasiliyMazhekin you may remove the row in this case ;) or add a class to this row and change direction ... you are not obliged to change the row class, i simply did it to show you how to correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra CSS as below :-

```
.no-gutters p, .no-gutters nav, .no-gutters h1 {width:100%;}
```